# Permalink format: singular or plural

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

The default is singular, e.g.

```
http://example.com/category/apple/
```

But I am wondering if it is better to use the plural form, e.g.

```
http://example.com/categories/apple/
```

Are there any guideline on this?

Comment: There is no matter what you use, you can change it on WP admin http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php you can change category name to whatever you want. If you like categories than use it.

Comment: @Tommix: Please add that as an answer, I think it's a very valid one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a simple rule that I follow (it's hard to explain, so I'll give examples):

- `http://example.com/categories/` <-- This plural form should mean that the page shows a list of all the categories in use on your site.

  Similarly, if it's "authors" (as in `http://example.com/authors/`), I'd expect the page to show a list (with or without descriptions — is your choice) of authors.
- Simply put, you can't use "category" (as in `http://example.com/category/`) and list all the categories under it. Kinda sounds meaningless, right? The point is, you never know when you'd have to create a listing as such => it's always best to leave out "plural" words for unless you have a specific/definite purpose (which makes sense).
- Also, people expect a URL to be a precise description of the page. For example, in my own case, when the title of an article in Google isn't descriptive enough, I look at the URL of the article to see if it's even close to what I am searching for. Just saying.

  Simply compare `http://example.com/category/technology/` versus `http://example.com/categories/technology/`

  - `http://example.com/category/technology/` tells me that I am going to the technology **category** on example.com
  - If I see `http://example.com/categories/technology/` my brain needs to think a little bit, and it will of course (in most cases), come to understand it like this — I am going to a page about technology which is one of the **categories** on example.com)
- Sometimes, URLs are structured to show content hierarchy. Take a look at this site's URL structure, for example (Notice it? Yeah, **"questions"**.):  `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53474/permalink-format-singular-or-plural`

  `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/` takes you to a list of all the questions on WP.SE <sup>[1]</sup>. `53474` is the post ID. That's it these are the essential parts as far as the system is concerned. The descriptive part of the URL, i.e. `permalink-format-singular-or-plural` is meant for search engines, and the visitors coming from search engines (AFAIK).

  The content hierarchy here? `Home > Questions > Post` (or say, Question) —- this made more sense to the people who built the Stack Exchange network, and so, they went ahead it.

  - The point should be clear by now — whatever you use in your URL, people **can** absolutely relate to it. There's no way it's NOT going to make sense at all. The point is, do you want to make easier on the brains of your readers/visitors? Then use the form of word (singular/plural) that makes more sense — precisely, in your case, the *singular* word makes sense => `http://example.com/category/apple/`

**[1]:** WP.SE => WordPress.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 16):

There are two reasons to keep the singular:

1. It is a common practice to use the singular. Don't break it unless you want to make it hard to remember your permalinks. Your readers are on other sites 99% of their time, they shouldn't have to learn something without a really good reward.
2. Plural forms are [harder to translate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq19-plurals.html). When I create custom taxonomies or post types I make the slugs translatable too. Singular forms are usually easier to translate, that may have been the origin for this practice.

Comment: +1. Besides, using the singular is simply *more semantic*. The URL does not lead to a resource that displays the archive index page for *multiple* categories, but rather the archive index page for a *single* category.

Comment: But I understand the askers point: If you go up one URL part to `example.com/category/` you expect a list of all categories (plural), and then `category` looks wrong.

Comment: But you'll *never* get that. `/category/` is a *virtual* URL construct. WordPress doesn't serve an actual page for `example.com/category/`.

Comment: @ChipBennett URL shortening is is not so uncommon. Some browser even offer a shortcut for that. I consider WordPress’ default behavior a bug.

Comment: @ChipBennett: Jakob Nielsen says we should make URLs  `that are "hackable" to allow users to move to higher levels of the information architecture by hacking off the end of the URL`.  So that `/category/` is a 404 seems undesirable.